# Curve Fitting with Python, with data from file

Tags: python

I am trying to fit data to an equation. The experimental data is accessed from a file (about 1000 x,y points) and to be fitted to the model called circuit. mple from the python site 
    http://cars9.uchicago.edu/software/python/lmfit/model.html
done for Gaussian fitting and simply replaced the equations. I am having a whole bunch of errors.

```
from numpy import*
from lmfit import  Model

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = loadtxt("C:/Users/susu/eq_real.dat")
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]



def circuit(x,a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5):

    C0=1.04*10**(-12)
    Cm=5.95*10**(-14)
    Lm=1.44*10**(-7)
    Rm=1.57
    Rs=0.431
    R0=2.44
    #Define parameters
    a0 = C0 + Cm
    a1 = C0 * Cm * (R0 + Rm)
    a2 = C0 * Cm * Lm
    a3 = -C0 * (R0 + Rs) - Cm * (Rm + Rs)
    a4 = -Cm*Lm-C0*Cm*(R0*Rm+R0*Rs+Rm*Rs)
    a5 = -C0 * Cm * Lm * (R0 + Rs)

    return((a1*x**2+a0*a3*x**2+a0*a5*x**4+a1*a4*x**4-a2*a3*x**4-
    a2*a5*x**6)/(a3**2*x**2+2*a3*a5*x**4+a4**2*x**4+2*a4*x**2+a5**2*x**6+1))


     gmodel = Model(circuit)
     result = gmodel.fit(y, x=x, a0=1.10*10**(-12), a1=2.48*10**(-25), 
     a2=8.92*10**(-33), a3= -3.11*10**(-12), a4= -8.57*10**(-21), a5= 
     -2.56*10**(-32))

     print(result.fit_report())

  plt.plot(x, y,         'bo')
  plt.plot(x, result.init_fit, 'k--')
  plt.plot(x, result.best_fit, 'r-')
  plt.show()
```

Comment: Please post the stack if you want people to have a look. You have some indentation trouble, but the code runs without trouble for me other than that.

Comment: Have you plotted your data to see, if they even remotely resemble the fit function? If so, have you changed the start value array to good estimates?

Comment: At first glance, you have parameters in `circuit` that are computed internally.  These computed values override whatever you pass in.  Post some data and your plot so far and someone may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your model function `circuit()` does not actually use its arguments `a0`, `a1`, etc to calculate the circuit response.  The values are hard-wired in, and so this function will always return the same value.  That is almost certainly not what you want. In addition, your code is not indented properly.  All of this makes me wonder whether this is the actual code you ran.  As suggested in the comments, post the actual code you ran and the full output.  Looking at a plot of the data and an initial model is often helpful to tell if your input parameters are close to reasonable.

Also, keep in mind that working with values that span more than about 10 orders of magnitude can be challenging for numerical codes and fitting in particular.  That is, you may want to recast your parameters to be in units of picoFarad, nanoHenry.  You can still include the proper scales in the calculation, but the fitting methods will have more difficulty finding good values for parameters that have values in the range 1.e-32 while others are in the range 1.e-7.  Try to keep the variable parameters to be refined in the fit are around same magnitude (say, within a factor of 10^6).